# Escalar Coleção no CosmosDB

Tags: microsoft-azure, cosmos-db, document-db

É possível escalar uma base de dados do tipo Document no CosmosDB? Se sim, é possível escalar somente uma coleção ao invés da base como um todo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na verdade, é exatamente assim que se escala no CosmosDB, vc escala apenas uma coleção, e não toda uma base de dados. Veja:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui eu estou selecionando para escalar apenas a *collection* `workspace` da *database* eventstore.